# How can I keep the print version of my Drupal pages showing up in Google's search results?

Tags: drupal, seo, google-search

When I use Google to search my own Drupal site I often get the print version of the pages in the results rather than the non-print version.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it?

For example, Google the following:  edition only site:community.screen-scraper.com

At least the first page of results contain links to the print versions of the pages.  The distinguishing characteristic of the URLs is the presence of "export".

*I do have Clean URLs enabled.*

Answer (score 1):

Add rel=nofollow to the links to your print versions. You should also look into setting up conical urls eg  http://drupal.org/project/nodewords

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to set up conical URLs for this situation.  If you have any examples I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above you could also add a noindex meta tag to the offending pages (via injecting the meta tag into the header for 'print' pages) and also sort out the pages that you don't want indexed with a robots.txt file.

Try these links for more info:

(Meta Tags) http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812

(Robots) http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Comment: Thanks, @SteveH. I added /book/export/ as a disallow to my robots.txt.  Now I'm just waiting for Google's indexing to update.  Do you happen to know of any tricks to expedite this?  I used Google's Webmaster Tools six days ago to "Fetch as Google" but the print pages are still showing up in search results.  Perhaps I'm being impatient.

Comment: No problem, good call on using Webmaster Tools (was meant to mention this to you). Unfortunately as with most things with google, it's just a case of being patient, although is your robots.txt file showing a 200 (success) status under blocked url's menu?. I don't believe there is a faster way to remove the types of pages that you want removed, although you can remove certain URL's using the tools as a request: https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59819 . Perhaps wait a bit longer and if they don't disappear from the search results try using the Remove url's request?

Comment: Sorry just to confirm when you use fetch as google, does it come up with 'Denied by robots.txt' as the fetch status? As if not your robots.txt file is not working correctly, so go back to the Blocked URLS page and check that it has both been downloaded and received a 200 (success) status, and then test a few url's at the bottom of this page. Hope it all goes well.

Comment: Yes, my robots.txt file does return 200 and is being read by Google.  I'll wait to see what happens.  Thanks, again.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for pointing out the remove URL's feature of WT.  I did that, as well.